# How to read the Google Drive doc content with content-type application/msword and application/pdf etc?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, java-io

I am able to get the content from files with content-type `text/plain`, but not those with content-type `application/msword` and `application/pdf`.

Is there any way to get the content and read it properly? Here is the code which is working perfectly with content-type: `text/plain`

```
HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory()
                  .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl())).execute();

BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getContent()));
System.out.println("Shorten Response: ");
for (String line = output.readLine(); line != null; line = output.readLine()) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used tika parser for that and in my case its working.
Plz check the code snippet:-

```
            HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory().
            buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl())).execute();

            Detector detector = new DefaultDetector();
            Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser(detector);
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(resp.getContent());
            ContentHandler handler2 = new BodyContentHandler(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            parser.parse(input, handler2, metadata, new ParseContext());
            String text = handler2.toString();
```

I used tika-app-1.3.jar for that. It's working with .pdf, .doc .docx, .text etc files.
And Thanks all for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both PDF and MSWORD formats are binary streams and as such not readable line-by-line. Try to read them into a byte[] buffer.

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive svc;
InputStream is = svc.getRequestFactory()
.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl("xxx")).execute().getContent();

public byte[] strm2Bytes(InputStream is) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    BufferedInputStream bufIS = null;
    if (is != null) try {
      bufIS = new BufferedInputStream(is);
      int cnt = 0;
      while ((cnt = bufIS.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, cnt);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    finally { try { if (bufIS != null) bufIS.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}} 
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
  }
```

But you'll get a raw file bytes and I don't really know what you want to do with it. Convert? Display? Normally, these byte buffers can be handed to 'decoders' (word reader, pdf reader, jpeg decoder, ....). But again, these readers / decoders usually accept InputStream directly so there is no need to byte-buffer them.

Comment: I want to index this data with content.

Comment: Not working i want only text data from the document nthing else. I need to add it in solr. In .text file i am getting all text data but in .pdf .doc i am getting some stream data . I want to convert it in text or in string in readable stuff.

Comment: i want to display the text data. Now plz tel me how to display this inputstream in readable form?

Comment: I have already answered your question 'how to read'. How to display - present the MIME types above is a different problem I am not familiar with. I work with JPEG images and in my situation I hand the buffer to a JPEG decoder and display a bitmap. As I mentioned in my answer above you have to find a 'decoder/presenter' for your raw data you downloaded.